# How to get the columnLabel (not columnName) from a cursor

Tags: cursors

I've seen code to do it with a result set, but the Python code I am using has a cursor not a result set.  It is thus printing the wrong labels for the columns.

```
select c1 as Hello, c2 as World from table
```

is labeling the columns as c1 and c2 rather than Hello and World.

I am tinkering with cli.py if that is useful help.

The python code looks like:

```
   cursor.execute(statement)
   if cursor.description is not None:
        headers = []
        for column in cursor.description:
            headers.append(column[0])
```

That last line is giving me the columnName not the columnLabel.

My unit tests (in Java) which uses a ResultSet show that the columnLabel is correct.  But, how to get it in the Python code using a cursor?